# Setting up SSH to Running EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I setting up EKS yesterday with the following command :

```
eksctl create cluster --name=eks-goup \
--nodegroup-name=standard-workers \
--node-type=t2.micro --nodes=2 --nodes-min=1 --nodes-max=2  \
--node-ami=auto --region eu-central-1
```

I using **AmazonLinux2** as server. I ve checked on the [AWS website which user to use](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectingMindTerm)

For Amazon Linux 2 or the Amazon Linux AMI, the user name is : **ec2-user.**

Before to try to connect to the instance i set the key-pair
***EC2-> Key-Pairs -> Create***

As well i check if Key-Pairs was available on my instance so i did ***EC2 -> Instances -> select the instance ->*** and check the Key pair name (  when i click on the link i see it )

I check also if the port 22 inbound is open and yes

```
22  TCP 0.0.0.0/0   eksctl-eks-goup-nodegroup-standard-workers-SG-3IWA6FZSARK5  
22  TCP ::/0
```

So i tried to connect to my instance by **SSH**

> ssh -vvv  -i EKX-25-03.pem ec2-user@3.1XX.XX6.13X

```
debug1: Connection established.

debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: EKX-25-03.pem
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:7xvxTqEpj5suvgb8RPC+LQw7hmNV701E89rR17UuqOI
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.

ec2-user@3.1XX.XX6.13X: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

What did i miss ??
Do i have to play with VPC ?? IAM ??

Comment: did you did this `chmod 400 /path_to_key/my_key.pem`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that gives you a different error. If the permissions are wrong ssh doesn't even try to connect.

Comment: Did my solution work?

Answer (score 0):

the solution to your problem would be this.

one would be incorrect permissions to your.pem file

```
  chmod 400 /path_to_key/my_key.pem
```